# Como puedo cargar un combobox dependiendo de la selección de otro combobox con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

Necesito a través de javascript que se seleccione en el combobox la comuna dependiendo de la region que seleccione en el combobox anterior
En mi models.py lo tengo del a siguiente manera:

```
class Region(models.Model):
nro_region = models.IntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name="Nro. Región")
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Comuna(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Entonces en mi template tengo 2 combobox, pero dependiendo de la región que selecciono, tengo que cargar las comunas que pertenecen a esa región.
Como lo puedo conseguir con javascript?? muchas gracias.

Comment: Un método sería integrar un evento "al hacer click" en el segundo combobox que cargue los items que tiene dentro, y que entonces ejecute una consulta a la base de datos o lo que utilices.

Answer (score 2):

Para tu pregunta tenemos que usar `onchange`

HTML :

```
<select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
    <option value="">Select combo</option>
    <option value="Value1">Text1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Text2</option>
    <option value="Value3">Text3</option>
    </select>



 <select id="comboB">

    </select>
```

javascript :

```
function getComboA(selectObject) {

    // aqui dependera de donde obtienes los datos para ingresar las opciones de tu combo, puede ser una invocacion `ajax`
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Text";
    option.value = "myvalue";
    var select = document.getElementById("comboB");
    select.appendChild(option); 
}
```

Espero te ayude, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer algo como esto, en donde usas el evento change para consultar por medio de ajax la informacion que manejas en tus modelos. cada vez que cambies de region se realizara una peticion y se cambiaran las opciones de tu combo comuna.
veo que utilizas MVC asi que seria enviar la info a tu controlador

```
 $("#micombo").change(function(){

    var region =$("#micombo").val(); 
        var connect, form, response, result;

        form = "region="+region; //informacion que enviaras a tu .py 
        connect = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        connect.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(connect.readyState == 4 && connect.status == 200) {                  
                var datos = JSON.parse(connect.responseText);
                //luego de la respuesta del servidor recorreras todas las comunas para llenar el segundo combo
                $.each( datos, function( key, value ) {

                    $("#miselect").append("<option value ='"+value.id+"'>"+value.descripcion+"</option>");
                });
            }
        }

        connect.open('GET','miPythonController.py',true);
        connect.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        connect.send(form);
});
```